# Nbconvertapp doesn't exist

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

I'm on Ubuntu, I'm using Python 2.7.6 and Ipython 4.0.3. I'm trying to convert a ipynb file to a pdf file. It gives the following error:

```
ipython nbconvert --to pdf mine.ipynb 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/ipython", line 6, in <module>
start_ipython()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line    119, in start_ipython
return launch_new_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config    /application.py", line 588, in launch_instance
app.initialize(argv)
File "<decorator-gen-111>", line 2, in initialize
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 74, in catch_config_error
return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 305, in initialize
super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).initialize(argv)
File "<decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 74, in catch_config_error
return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 386, in initialize
self.parse_command_line(argv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 300, in parse_command_line
return super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).parse_command_line(argv)
File "<decorator-gen-4>", line 2, in parse_command_line
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 74, in catch_config_error
return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 485, in parse_command_line
return self.initialize_subcommand(subc, subargv)
File "<decorator-gen-3>", line 2, in initialize_subcommand
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 74, in catch_config_error
return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 416, in initialize_subcommand
subapp = import_item(subapp)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipython_genutils/importstring.py", line 31, in import_item
module = __import__(package, fromlist=[obj])
ImportError: No module named nbconvert.nbconvertapp
```

I googled the last line and found nothing. Any idea is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How did you go about installing Jupyter?

Answer (score 9):

You probably have to install `nbconvert`:

```
pip install nbconvert
```

IPython recommends to use pip (or conda) for installation:

> IPython relies on a number of other Python packages. Installing using a package manager like pip or conda will ensure the necessary packages are installed. If you install manually, it’s up to you to make sure dependencies are installed. They’re not listed here, because they may change from release to release, so a static list will inevitably get out of date.

In the [old documentation](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/install/install.html#dependencies-for-nbconvert-converting-notebooks-to-various-formats) and [a bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=747437) [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/) is named as dependency and [this bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=747437), to be installed as:

```
sudo apt-get install pandoc
```